# Windows 10 Explorer Search field: Search for files beginning with "1-"

Tags: windows-explorer, search

I am looking for the pattern to use the windows explorer search bar to find all files (Not folders)
in the current directory and all sub directories that start with the pattern `1-`
for example the file `1-file.txt` should be found but the file `1file.txt` not

I tried several syntax approaches that I know from GNU Grep or SED.

But the windows search bar always returns non sense, like files that just contain the number `1` somewhere in the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you open to using 3rd party tools? If you are, [Everything by voidtools.com](https://www.voidtools.com/) is pretty good and has very fast search capability. The tool indexes your whole computer and show you result as you typed.

Comment: works well out of the box fast index, understandable which data will be scanned. Does not try to connect to the internet (a lot of freeware does)

Answer (score 2):

In some delightfully hard-to-find [MS Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#query-operators), there's information regarding several string-specific query operators. One of them is `COP_VALUE_STARTSWITH`:

> Operator: `COP_VALUE_STARTSWITH`
> Symbol: `~<`
> Example: `System.FileName:~<"C++ Primer"`
> Description: `Finds items where the file name begins with the characters "C++ Primer".`

So, to find only files that begin with "`1-`", use:

```
FileName:~<1-
```

Other operators include:

- COP_VALUE_ENDSWITH: `~>`
- COP_VALUE_CONTAINS: `~=` or `~~`
- COP_VALUE_NOTCONTAINS: `~!`
- COP_DOSWILDCARDS: `~`

`VALUE_CONTAINS` overcomes the default word-based (as opposed to character-based) nature of Windows Indexing. Using `name:~~cess`:

[image]

`DOSWILDCARDS` allows the wildcard characters `?` and `*` to be used in quoted strings. And characters that are part of seach syntax, such as `(`, `)`, `[`, and `]`, must be in quotes to interpreted as search characters. So to find files that have parenthetical indices at the end of the filename, use  `FileName:~"*(*).*"`

[image]

Again, the complete list is here:

[Using Advanced Query Syntax Programmatically - Query Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#query-operators)

Answer (score 0):

See http://hs.windows.microsoft.com/hhweb/content/m-en-us/p-6.2/id-8d6963c6-f737-4009-a061-22cbb976bdc3/

```
name:"1-*.*"
```

But the options on the search tab affect what will happen.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, finds lots of files and folders that just contain "1" in the name somewhere